# Django tinymce skin

Tags: django, tinymce

Добрый день!
Подскажите пожалуйста, почему установленный на Django tinymce  редактор имеет стиль такого вида

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

на сайте в превью он выглядит достаточно симпатичнее и больше функционала

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как его расширить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG = {
    'theme': "lightgray",
}
```

Comment: Это не помогает. Django по умолчанию ищет css в default. Где эти пути можно переопределить?

Comment: У меня с десяток проектов используют django-tinymce и во всех работает установка темы в конфигурации.

Comment: Спасибо! collectstatic помог, теперь конфиг считывает